# Pandas: Selecting rows for which groupby.sum() satisfies condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In pandas I have a dataframe of the form:

```
>>> import pandas as pd  
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[51,51,51,24,24,24,31], 'x':[0,1,0,0,1,1,0]})
>>> df

ID   x
51   0
51   1
51   0
24   0
24   1
24   1
31   0
```

For every 'ID' the value of 'x' is recorded several times, it is either 0 or 1. I want to select those rows from `df` that contain an 'ID' for which 'x' is 1 at least twice.

For every 'ID' I manage to count the number of times 'x' is 1, by

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['x'].sum()

ID
51    1
24    2
31    0
```

But I don't know how to proceed from here. I would like the following output:

```
ID   x
24   0
24   1
24   1
```

Comment: Use group by filter to get the IDs and then use the result to query your main table.I am not a pandas expert so not sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `filter`

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda s: s.x.sum()>=2)
```

Output:

```
   ID  x
3  24  0
4  24  1
5  24  1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[51,51,51,24,24,24,31], 'x':[0,1,0,0,1,1,0]})
df.loc[df.groupby(['ID'])['x'].transform(func=sum)>=2,:]
out:
   ID  x
3  24  0
4  24  1
5  24  1
```

Comment: You don't need the second indexer and use `'sum'` `df.loc[df.groupby(['ID'])['x'].transform('sum')>=2]`

Comment: @piRSquared thank you ~ Also your answer help me learn a lot ~

Comment: I'm glad.  Hope to see more of your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.bincount` and `pd.factorize`
*alternative advance technique to draw better performance*

```
f, u = df.ID.factorize()
df[np.bincount(f, df.x.values)[f] >= 2]

   ID  x
3  24  0
4  24  1
5  24  1
```

---

In obnoxious `one-liner` form

```
df[(lambda f, w: np.bincount(f, w)[f] >= 2)(df.ID.factorize()[0], df.x.values)]

   ID  x
3  24  0
4  24  1
5  24  1
```

---

`np.bincount` and `np.unique`
*I could've used `np.unique` with the `return_inverse` parameter to accomplish the same exact thing.  But, `np.unique` will sort the array and will change the time complexity of the solution.*

```
u, f = np.unique(df.ID.values, return_inverse=True)
df[np.bincount(f, df.x.values)[f] >= 2]
```

---

One-liner

```
df[(lambda f, w: np.bincount(f, w)[f] >= 2)(np.unique(df.ID.values, return_inverse=True)[1], df.x.values)]
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df[(lambda f, w: np.bincount(f, w)[f] >= 2)(df.ID.factorize()[0], df.x.values)]
%timeit df[(lambda f, w: np.bincount(f, w)[f] >= 2)(np.unique(df.ID.values, return_inverse=True)[1], df.x.values)]
%timeit df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda s: s.x.sum()>=2)
%timeit df.loc[df.groupby(['ID'])['x'].transform(func=sum)>=2]
%timeit df.loc[df.groupby(['ID'])['x'].transform('sum')>=2]
```

*small data*

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 302 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 241 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 ms per loop
```

*large data*

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ID=np.random.randint(100, size=10000),
        x=np.random.randint(2, size=10000)
    ))

1000 loops, best of 3: 528 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 847 µs per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 20.9 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.47 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop
```

*larger data*

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ID=np.random.randint(100, size=100000),
        x=np.random.randint(2, size=100000)
    ))

1000 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.44 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 29.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.84 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.74 ms per loop
```