# Filter dataframe by group size

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that I want to filter based on group size. For example, I want to group by 'Name' and 'Date' and get groups which size is greater than 2.

```
   Name     Date Symbol
0  Ajay  2018_Q1     AA
1  Ajay  2018_Q1     BB
2  Ajay  2018_Q1     CC
3  Ajay  2018_Q1     DD
4  Ajay  2019_Q1     AA
5  Faye  2019_Q1     DD
6  Faye  2019_Q1     AA
7  Faye  2019_Q1     ZZ
8  Faye  2018_Q1     AA
9  Faye  2018_Q1     EE
```

So the output dataframe should look like this:

```
   Name     Date Symbol
0  Ajay  2018_Q1     AA
1  Ajay  2018_Q1     BB
2  Ajay  2018_Q1     CC
3  Ajay  2018_Q1     DD
5  Faye  2019_Q1     DD
6  Faye  2019_Q1     AA
7  Faye  2019_Q1     ZZ
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Just add .ge(2) to the end of your group by statement

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ge'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Selecting rows for which groupby.sum() satisfies condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531696/pandas-selecting-rows-for-which-groupby-sum-satisfies-condition)

Comment: Sorry. Shud have tried it first. It needs a lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter):

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Date']).filter(lambda x: x['Symbol'].size > 2)
```

or

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Date']).filter(lambda x: x.shape[0] > 2)
```

Output:

```
   Name     Date Symbol
0  Ajay  2018_Q1     AA
1  Ajay  2018_Q1     BB
2  Ajay  2018_Q1     CC
3  Ajay  2018_Q1     DD
5  Faye  2019_Q1     DD
6  Faye  2019_Q1     AA
7  Faye  2019_Q1     ZZ
```

Comment: Note that `.filter()` is slow, as explained in [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#the-filter-method). You can use `.transform()` to speed things up, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68637343/1397843)